# Powershell / Powercli script Cronjob

Tags: powershell, vmware-esxi, ubuntu-16.04, powercli

I made a Powershell script which uses Powercli to create and delete snapshots on my two Esxi hosts, but for some reason the Cronjob isn't working. In the syslog I can see the following message:

> (v6.1.0-preview.2:1:80)
>   [Perftrack_ConsoleStartupStop:PowershellConsoleStartup.WinStop.Informational]
>   PowerShell console is ready for user input

If I directly execute the scripts, they work without any issue. Here is the crontab:

```
\# m h  dom mon dow   command

\* \* \* \* \* /usr/local/bin/vsphere-influxdb-go
0 22 \* \* \* sudo cp -r /dockerdata/ /Storage/01\_Privat/02\_Tech/02\_Home\_Network/03\_Backup/01\_Docker/
0 22 \* \* \* /usr/local/bin/esx-1-create-new-snapshots.ps1
0 22 \* \* \* /usr/local/bin/esx-1-remove-snapshots-older-than-5-days.ps1
0 22 \* \* \* /usr/local/bin/esx-2-create-new-snapshots.ps1
0 22 \* \* \* /usr/local/bin/esx-2-remove-snapshots-older-than-5-days.ps1
```

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: How are you calling powershell in your scripts?

Comment: #!/usr/bin/pwsh -Command